# XCODE: How to get the tag value in a function?

Tags: xcode

I used a single label and split the word "**HELLO**". Now I need to match the word in another function `-(void)matchWords`, but the probem is only the last label is getting matched. I cannot match the other label.

For instance the word "**HELLO**" is there and when I click **'H'** the letter **'H'** should be highlighted in any colour , but the problem is that only **'o'** get's highlighted for any matchable letters from input...I used **iTag** to set the tag value for splitted  lables containing **unicharacters**.

Here is my function:

```
- (IBAction)onClick1:(id)sender {

NSString *title = [(UIButton *)sender currentTitle];
for(i=0;i<vCount;i++) {
    Str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[StrName characterAtIndex:i]];
            if([title isEqualToString:Str]){
   MyLable1.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
 }}}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Your example seems to suggest that you are comparing each letter of HELLO in turn with the whole word HELLO - which is ilogical and doesn't make sense.

Comment: its not like that.... i said when i click H in the keyboard the letter H should be compared with "HELLO", and if present the Letter H in HELLO should be highlighted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just use something like:

```
NSString *searchWord = @"Hello";    //The word to search against
NSString *searchChar = (UIButton *)sender.title;    //The character being searched
if ([searchWord rangeOfString:searchChar].location != NSNotFound)    //If found, highlight label
{
MyLable1.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}
```

Comment: i got the answer but since i have only 7 reputation i cant answer my own question, any ways thank u Andrei Filip... ill post once i get 10 reps

Answer (score 1):

```
- (IBAction)onClick1:(id)sender {

    NSString *title = [(UIButton *)sender currentTitle];
    for(i=0;i<vCount;i++) {
    for (NSString* key in Name){
    NSLog(@"Name");
    UILabel *Selected = (UILabel*)[self.view viewWithTag:[key intValue]];
    if ([title isEqualToString:Selected.text]) { 
    pStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[pStrName characterAtIndex:i]];
    Selected.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

      }
   }
}
```

I used this and got the output running successfully.

Comment: Enjoy the +1 and reputation :)